# How can I hide columns whose value is null in React-Table.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a working React Table with columns for viewing a Marathon data. The Half Marathon however uses all the same columns except for 2. If my data has `null` for a column how can I dynamically tell React-Table to hide it? Here is a sample column from the `Columns` array:

```js
{
    id: "time_35k",
    Header: "35k",
    className: "hide-mobile",
    headerClassName: "hide-mobile",
    style: {
      textAlign: "center"
    },
    show: true,
    accessor: runner => formatTime(runner.time_35k),
    getProps: (state, rowInfo, column) => {
      if (state.value === null) {
        newColumn.show = false;
        newColumn.style.display = "none";
        newColumn.headerStyle.display = "none";
        return {
          style: {
            display: "none"
          },
          headerStyle: {
            display: "none"
          }
        };
      }
    }
  },
```

and here is a sample half-marathon data object:

```js
{
  "place": 1,
  "name": "Keith Meyer",
  "age": 22,
  "sex_place": 1,
  "sex": "M",
  "rank": 2,
  "time_5k": 987,
  "rank_5k": 1,
  "time_10k": 1976,
  "rank_10k": 1,
  "time_15k": 2981,
  "time_35k": null, // TODO: hide this table column
  "time": 4202,
  "pace": 321,
  "city": "Edwardsville",
  "state": "IL",
  "bib_number": 5011,
  "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkirVvr6acU&t=8s"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those wondering why this is not working: `show` is deprecated. Use `initialstate.hiddenColumns` instead.

Check:
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1804

Answer (score 2):

i resolve the problem, with this option:

```
//...code definition table here
} = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      initialState: { 
        pageIndex: 0,
        hiddenColumns: ['id'].  //use property option, in columns define id name "id"
      },
    },
    usePagination
  );
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to only hide columns who's data is null

Answer (score 1):

I too had a similar need to @Trenton. I wanted to hide columns who's data was null. here is my solution. :D

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
    // for each column who's data is null, hide that column.

    let emptyColumns = [];

    _.forEach(data[0], function(value, key) {
      if (value === "") emptyColumns.push(key);
    });

    emptyColumns.push("parentEmailAddress");

    setHiddenColumns(emptyColumns);
  }, [setHiddenColumns, columns]);
```

After many days of searching to see if there was a complete lazy function to do this, I found there wasn't apart from setHiddenColumns ([docs here](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#instance-properties)).
I ended up with what most people would have done I think, and just iterated through the object to find null values, and add that key to an array `emptyColumns` which I passed to `setHiddenColumns`. Job Done :)

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to `setHiddenColumns`.

Important to remember to import `setHiddenColumns` from `react-table` AND to include it in the `tableInstance` const. 

It won't work unless it's in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your show option in the column information to be based on your data instead of just true. e.g.

```
{
    id: "time_35k",
    Header: "35k",
    className: "hide-mobile",
    headerClassName: "hide-mobile",
    style: {
      textAlign: "center"
    },
    show: data.columnName,
    accessor: runner => formatTime(runner.time_35k),
    getProps: (state, rowInfo, column) => {
      if (state.value === null) {
        newColumn.show = false;
        newColumn.style.display = "none";
        newColumn.headerStyle.display = "none";
        return {
          style: {
            display: "none"
          },
          headerStyle: {
            display: "none"
          }
        };
      }
    }
  },
```

if data.columnName is null it will be falsy and your column should hide.